# Filter out difference from two files into seprate files

Tags: shell-script, shell

I have 2 files for comparison. I want Transfer the different records from both the files in two separate file.

**File1**

```
A|B|C|D

1|2|3|5

E|F|G|H
```

**File2**

```
A|B|C|D

1|2|3|4

E|F|I|H
```

Output Like...
**File3.**

```
1|2|3|5

E|F|G|H
```

**File4.**

```
1|2|3|4

E|F|I|H
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using `comm`.

```
comm file1 file2 -23 > file3
comm file1 file2 -13 > file4
```

`-23` means "only lines unique to FILE1"

`-13` means "only lines unique to FILE2"

Comment: you can add "--nocheck-order" to ignore warning...

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
diff File1 File2 | grep "^<" | sed 's/^< //g' > File3
diff File1 File2 | grep "^>" | sed 's/^> //g' > File4
```

output:

```
cat File3
1|2|3|5
E|F|G|H

cat File4
1|2|3|4
E|F|I|H
```

Comment: Thank you. its working fine.